# Error converting data type varchar to bigint in select Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here is my code,All colums are bigint.It gives Error converting data type varchar to bigint.When I remove 'E' it converted blank to zero
Why It converted to bigint while I'm using Cast and assign to Varchar Variable.

```
declare @Result as varchar(500)=''
    SELECT @Result +=cast(ISNULL(L4,'E') as Varchar) + ',' 
    FROM MembershipLevel where L3=18
    select @Result as Result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code

```
declare @Result as varchar(500)=''
    SELECT @Result +=ISNULL(cast L4 as Varchar,'E') + ',' 
    FROM MembershipLevel where L3=18
    select @Result as Result
```